# How to change a attribute in dataframe column using pyspark which is nested array of struct?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

While I have found a lot of questions similar to this one, but none of them was exactly solving my problem.
I have an input JSON as following

```
{
    "Header": {
        "file_schema_version": "1.0"
    },
    "Records": [
        {
            "sequence_number": 1,
            "ID": "9024147714"
        },
        {
            "sequence_number": 2,
            "ID": "9029218142"
        }
    ],
    "Footer": {
        "record_count": 2
    }
}
```

The output I expect is a new file with updated ID fields as following.

```
{
    "Header": {
        "file_schema_version": "1.0"
    },
    "Records": [
        {
            "sequence_number": 1,
            "ID": "9024"
        },
        {
            "sequence_number": 2,
            "ID": "9029"
        }
    ],
    "Footer": {
        "record_count": 2
    }
}
```

Records is an array of struct. I have got up to creating a new DataFrame with updated ID. I am not sure how to put it back in the file with Header and Footer intact.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").config(conf=SparkConf()).getOrCreate()
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.json('D:\user\Documents\DATA.json')
df.printSchema()
df.show()

records = df.select(f.explode("Records").alias("RecordsExploded")).select("RecordsExploded.*")
records.printSchema()
records.show()

records = records.withColumn("ID", f.substring(records["ID"], 1, 4))
records.show()
```

This is the output that I get from above.

```
root
 |-- Footer: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- record_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- file_schema_version: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Records: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sequence_number: long (nullable = true)

+------+------+--------------------+
|Footer|Header|             Records|
+------+------+--------------------+
|   [2]| [1.0]|[[9024147714, 1],...|
+------+------+--------------------+

root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sequence_number: long (nullable = true)

+----------+---------------+
|        ID|sequence_number|
+----------+---------------+
|9024147714|              1|
|9029218142|              2|
+----------+---------------+

+----+---------------+
|  ID|sequence_number|
+----+---------------+
|9024|              1|
|9029|              2|
+----+---------------+
```

Comment: What you you mean by "putting back in the file" ? overwrite the entire file, keep and only update the IDs ? Elaborate on this. Spark, by default doesn't support updates on the rows, like a standards SQl

Comment: I want to create a new JSON file with the updated ID field as shown in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
df.show(truncate=False)
+------+------+----------------------------------+
|Footer|Header|Records                           |
+------+------+----------------------------------+
|[2]   |[1.0] |[[9024147714, 1], [9029218142, 2]]|
+------+------+----------------------------------+

df
.withColumn("Records",explode($"Records"))
.withColumn("Records",struct(substring(col("Records.Id"),1,4).alias("ID"),col("Records.sequence_number").alias("sequence_number")))
.groupBy(struct(col("Footer"),col("Header")).alias("group_data"))
.agg(collect_list(col("Records")).alias("Records"))
.select("group_data.*","Records")
.show(truncate=False)

+------+------+----------------------+
|Footer|Header|Records               |
+------+------+----------------------+
|[2]   |[1.0] |[[9024, 1], [9029, 2]]|
+------+------+----------------------+
```

Comment: This one is more readable and easy to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After **`exploding`** Try with groupBy on **`Header,Footer`** columns then `collect_list` to reconstruct the json that required.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

#sample data
df.printSchema()
#|-- Footer: struct (nullable = true)
#|    |-- record_count: long (nullable = true)
#|-- Header: struct (nullable = true)
#|    |-- file_schema_version: string (nullable = true)
#|-- Records: array (nullable = true)
#|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#|    |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
#|    |    |-- sequence_number: long (nullable = true)

df.show(10,False)
#+------+------+----------------------------------+
#|Footer|Header|Records                           |
#+------+------+----------------------------------+
#|[2]   |[1.0] |[[9024147714, 1], [9029218142, 2]]|
#+------+------+----------------------------------+

df1=df.withColumn("nn",f.explode(f.col("Records"))).\
select("*","nn.*").\
drop(*["nn","Records"]).\
withColumn("ID",f.substring(f.col("ID"),1,4)).\
groupBy("Footer","Header").\
agg(f.collect_list(f.struct(f.col("ID"),f.col("sequence_number"))).alias("Records"))

df1.show(10,False)
#+------+------+----------------------+
#|Footer|Header|Records               |
#+------+------+----------------------+
#|[2]   |[1.0] |[[9024, 1], [9029, 2]]|
#+------+------+----------------------+

#view json object in cli
df1.toJSON().collect()
#['{"Footer":{"record_count":2},"Header":{"file_schema_version":"1.0"},"Records":[{"ID":"9024","sequence_number":1},{"ID":"9029","sequence_number":2}]}']

#write in json format
df1.write.format("json").mode("overwrite").path("<HDFS_PATH>")
```